# Extrapolate exact same rows from yearly to monthly data point in python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, resampling

I have example dataframe in yearly granularity:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": ["2020-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2022-01-01"],
    "cost": [100, 1000, 150],
    "person": ["Tom","Jerry","Brian"]
})
```

I want to create dataframe with monthly granularity without any estimation methods (just repeat a row 12 times for each year. So in a result from this 3 row dataframe I would like to get 36 rows exactly like:

```
2020-01-01   /   100   /   Tom
2020-02-01   /   100   /   Tom
2020-03-01   /   100   /   Tom
2020-04-01   /   100   /   Tom
2020-05-01   /   100   /   Tom

[...]

2022-10-01   /   150   /   Brian
2022-11-01   /   150   /   Brian
2022-12-01   /   150   /   Brian
```

I tried

```
df.resample('M', on = 'date').apply(lambda x:x)
```

but cant seem to get it working...

Im beginner so forgive me my ignorance
Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do that.

```
count = len(df)
for var in df[['date','cost','person']].values:
    for i in range(2,13):
        df.loc[count] = [(var[0][0:5] + "{:02d}".format(i) + var[0][7:]),var[1], var[2]]
        count += 1

df = df.sort_values('date')
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should also work,

```
#Typecasting
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

#Making new dataframe based on frequency
op = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start=df['date'].min(), end=df['date'].max()+pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=11),freq='MS'),columns = ['date'])

#merging both results on year using merge( with outer join)
res = pd.merge(df,op,left_on=df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.year), right_on = op['date'].apply(lambda x: x.year), how = 'outer')

#dropping key columns from left side
res.drop(['key_0','date_x'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```